# MyBatis - writing mappers for Oracle while testing against H2

Tags: java, oracle, unit-testing, h2, mybatis

I'm currently writing MyBatis mappers that generate queries which should run against an Oracle DB in QA and Production.

However, in order to run proper unit-tests on these mappers, I'm using the H2 database with the same schema and some mocked data. This works fine for the most part, except where there are discrepancies between standard SQL, H2 SQL and Oracle SQL.

One example would be multi-row inserts which have a different syntax for Oracle.

Since I don't want to write separate mappers (which would lose the whole point of unit-testing these mappers) for H2 and Oracle and would like to avoid going DB roundtrips as much as possible., what would you propose I should do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind writing two seperate sql statements, configure databaseIdProvider might be able to help you, in the mapper xml you will then be doing something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="CityMapper">

    <select id="findById" resultType="City" databaseId="oracle">

    </select>

    <select id="findById" resultType="City" databaseId="h2">

    </select>

</mapper>
```

Comment: This approach might be the way I'll do it. The only problem with it is that the Oracle query remains untested until it is actually run against Oracle.